# Oracle SQL Generate XML to Local Server

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

I have a single table with below columns and based on these columns, I need to generate below XML which has lot of contant values.

PHX_BADGE,MODELTYPE,EFFECTIVE_DATE,PROGRAMID,CONFIGURATIONID

Issue:

- I need to generate the result obtained on local server automatically, but not able to acheive it.
- Also, EFFECTIVE DATE declared as XMLForest(PROGRAMID "value", EFFECTIVE_DATE "startDate") need to be converted to timezone, but code I am getting literal string error. Format required for date "2023-06-01T00:00:00-07:00

Can someone guide me, how can I acheive this.

Note: I need to generate XML for each row and there are total of 110 rows.

Below is what I wrote and it generated result with value as '(XMLTYPE)'. I have to view this editor.

```
SELECT XMLElement("SDPSyncMessage", 
                  XMLAttributes('http://www.emeter.com/energyip/syncinterface/v8' AS
                                  "xmlns",'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' AS
                                  "xmlns:xsi",
                                'http://www.emeter.com/energyip/syncinterface/v8 UniversalSyncInterface.xsd' AS
                                  "xsi:schemaLocation"),
                  XMLElement("header",
                    XMLElement("verb",'create'),
                    XMLElement("noun",'SDPSync'),
                    XMLElement("revision",'1'),
                    XMLElement("dateTime",TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(sysdate,'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSTZH:TZM')),
                    XMLElement("source",'CONV'),
                    XMLElement("messageID",'test01'),
                    XMLElement("syncMode",'sync'),
                    XMLElement("optimizationLevel",'Optimistic')                                      
                  ),                  
                XMLElement("payload",
                XMLElement("device",
                  XMLForest(phx_badge "mRID", name "deviceClass", modeltype "model"),
                  XMLElement("status",'Installed'),
                  XMLElement("type",'Meter'),
                  XMLElement("deviceFunctionType",'N'),
                  XMLElement("parameter",
                    XMLElement("name",'Configuration ID'),
                    XMLForest(CONFIGURATIONID "value", EFFECTIVE_DATE "startDate")),
                    XMLElement("parameter",
                    XMLElement("name",'Program ID'),
                    XMLForest(PROGRAMID "value", EFFECTIVE_DATE "startDate"))
                  ))) AS "RESULT"
   FROM ASSETS
   where phx_loc = '816840009'

Expected Output

<SDPSyncMessage xmlns="http://www.emeter.com/energyip/syncinterface/v8">
    <header>
        <verb>SDPSync</verb>    <!-- CONSTANT -->
        <noun>SDPSync</noun>    <!-- CONSTANT -->
        <revision>1</revision>  <!-- CONSTANT -->
        <dateTime>2023-08-21</dateTime>     <!-- sysdate -->
        <source>CIS</source>    <!-- CONSTANT -->
        <messageID>test</messageID>     <!-- CONSTANT -->
        <syncMode>Sync</syncMode>   <!-- CONSTANT -->
        <optimizationLevel>Optimistic</optimizationLevel>       <!-- CONSTANT -->
    </header>
    <payload>
        <device>
            <mRID>3608246</mRID>  <!-- PHX_BADGE -->
            <model>RXRSD</model>    <!-- MODELTYPE -->
            <status>Installed</status>  <!-- CONSTANT -->
            <type>Meter</type>  <!-- CONSTANT -->
            <parameter>
                <name>Configuration ID</name>   <!-- CONSTANT -->
                <value>001</value>  <!-- PHX_BADGE -->
                <startDate>2017-02-23 00:00:00</startDate>  <!-- EFFECTIVE_DATE -->
            </parameter>
            <parameter>
                <name>Program ID</name> <!-- CONSTANT -->
                <value>03</value>   <!-- PROGRAMID -->
                <startDate>2017-02-23 00:00:00</startDate>  <!-- EFFECTIVE_DATE -->
            </parameter>
        </device>       
    </payload>
</SDPSyncMessage>
```

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in SQL. 
(3) Desired XML output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your RDBMS version (SELECT * FROM v$version;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is this part:

```
TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(sysdate,'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSTZH:TZM')
```

`SYSDATE` returns a `DATE` value. **Never** use `TO_TIMESTAMP` (or `TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ` or `TO_DATE`) on a values which is already a `TIMESTAMP` (or `DATE`)

You need to format the TIMESTAMP to certain format, try this one:

```
XMLElement("dateTime", TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSTZH:TZM'))
```

However, in expected output you ask for `<dateTime>2023-08-21</dateTime>`, you may use this:

```
XMLElement("dateTime", TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP, 'YYYY-MM-DD'))
```

Saving a file works like this. First create a procedure to save the file:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SaveFile(
    FileContent IN OUT NOCOPY CLOB, 
    FolderName IN VARCHAR2, 
    FileName IN VARCHAR2, 
    UTF8 IN BOOLEAN DEFAULT TRUE) AS
        
    BUFFER VARCHAR2(4096 CHAR);
    OFFSET PLS_INTEGER := 1;
    FileLength INTEGER;
    amount PLS_INTEGER := 1024;
    fhandle UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
    
BEGIN

    FileLength := DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(FileContent);
    IF UTF8 THEN
        fhandle := UTL_FILE.FOPEN_NCHAR(FolderName, FileName, open_mode => 'w', max_linesize => 32000);
    ELSE
        fhandle := UTL_FILE.FOPEN(FolderName, FileName, open_mode => 'w', max_linesize => 32000);
    END IF;
        
    LOOP
        EXIT WHEN OFFSET > FileLength;
        DBMS_LOB.READ(FileContent, amount, OFFSET, BUFFER);
        IF UTF8 THEN
            UTL_FILE.PUT_NCHAR(fhandle, BUFFER);
        ELSE
            UTL_FILE.PUT(fhandle, BUFFER);
        END IF;     
        UTL_FILE.FFLUSH(fhandle);
        OFFSET := OFFSET + amount;
    END LOOP;
    UTL_FILE.FCLOSE (fhandle);

END SaveFile;
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY XML_OUTPUT_FOLDER AS '/var/app/out';
GRANT EXECUTE, READ, WRITE ON DIRECTORY XML_OUTPUT_FOLDER TO ... ;

DECLARE
    xmlContent CLOB;
SELECT

    SELECT XMLELEMENT("SDPSyncMessage", 'foo').getClobVal() 
    INTO xmlContent
    FROM dual;

    Pmd_Util.SaveFile(xmlContent, 'XML_OUTPUT_FOLDER', 'bar.xml');
    DBMS_LOB.FREETEMPORARY(xmlContent);

END;
```

Comment: Thanks for the details, my timestamp issue is resolved, but still I am not able to get the part where to generate the XML on file server, what changes could I make to the above query to get it working.

Comment: Thanks for the details, I used the code partially and instead of UTL_FILE used, dbms_xslprocessor.clob2file and got the desired result.
Thanks for the guidance

Comment: @user3792741 be aware of procedure DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR.CLOB2FILE has been deprecated starting in Oracle Database 12c release 12.2.